# @file_get_contents and wp_remote_get

Tags: errors, wp-remote-get

`$content = json_decode(@file_get_contents($query));`
what correctly replacement for @file_get_contents in this string? 
if i just replace @file_get_contents for @wp_remote_get i get error

> Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in example.php on line 88

Answer (score 2):

Check the docs. `file_get_contents()` and  `wp_remote_get()` are not equivalent. [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) returns a string. [`wp_remote_get()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get) returns either an array or a `WP_Error` object. You need to look at [`wp_remote_post()` to see the format of that array](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_post):

```
Array
(
    [headers] => Array
        (
            [date] => Thu, 30 Sep 2010 15:16:36 GMT
            [server] => Apache
            [x-powered-by] => PHP/5.3.3
            [x-server] => 10.90.6.243
            [expires] => Thu, 30 Sep 2010 03:16:36 GMT
            [cache-control] => Array
                (
                    [0] => no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
                    [1] => post-check=0, pre-check=0
                )

            [vary] => Accept-Encoding
            [content-length] => 1641
            [connection] => close
            [content-type] => application/php
        )
    [body] => <html>This is a website!</html>
    [response] => Array
        (
            [code] => 200
            [message] => OK
        )

    [cookies] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

I am guessing that the part you want is the `body`. You'd want to do something like this (very minimal but illustrative):

```
$content = wp_remote_get($query);
if (!is_wp_error($content)) {
  $content = json_decode($content['body']);
}
```